# How do we run two A/B tests in Google optimize but only letting visitors enter one of the a/b tests?

Tags: google-optimize

For Example, We have two pages home page and contact page and both have their own variants in google optimize. So when visitor visit homepage and get the new variant from google optimize then it should not see a new variant of contact page when visitor redirects to contact page and vise Versa. Hope you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to track which variations users get into using cookies and target accordingly. So, let's say your user lands on the home page and is bucketed into the new variant. You use custom JS to drop a cookie along the lines of user_has_seen_new_variant=true, and in your second experiment you target based on whether or not people have that cookie.

Another approach would maybe be to combine your experiments into one, where you're targeting both pages. That way you would have control over what people are seeing on either page.

Comment: How can I combine experiments into one? @joshcoles

Comment: If we go with the first solution, it can affect google analytics or other services of google, because google shares the cookies in different services ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @AounRaza. If your goal is for your users to have a consistent experience across the site, you could have just one variant where you are targeting both the home page and the contact page, and making changes with custom js/css within that one variant. That way if they're bucketed into variant A on the home page and then move to the contact page, they're still getting the same experience.